# How to create an List of int arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

I want to create a list and each element of it is an array, similarly to an array of structs in C language.
Can it be done in c# and how if it can? 
Thanks very much!

*Wrong:
`List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>;`*

Comment: How do you create a list of `int`? If you can do that, just add `[]`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis at the end of your new clause.

`List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>();`

Answer (score 16):

If you know your starting values you can also initialize it like so:

```
List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>
{
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new int[] { val1, val2, val3 },
    otherIntArray
};
```

Answer (score 7):

```
List<Int[]> arrList = new List<Int[]>();
int[] ArrayOfInts = new int[10];
```

fill as required

```
arrList.Add(ArrayOfInts);
```